# Extracting data from depot files generated by Perfroce

Tags: perforce, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, p4v, perforce-client-spec

Many years ago I had a Perforce server hosting an Unreal Engine 4 project, but it's no longer active and I unfortunately don't have access to it. All I have left are some depot folders. There's a specific folder with a bunch of FBX files that I need access to, but the file shows as a folder named something like this: file.uasset,d and file.fbx,d and within them are zip files.

Is there anyway for me to convert these folders into actual FBX files? Any tools or anything out there? Or do I need a server to upload these onto a depot for perfroce to understand what to do with them? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried opening them in Perforce without a workspace or server and there wasn't much I could do with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the server root folder (the one with the `db.*` files), you may be able to start up P4D and just access the depot normally.  If you have a checkpoint file, you can use that to reconstruct the db.* files.

If all you have are the depot archives, you can unzip the files inside them (using regular old `gzip` or similar) to retrieve the original content.  E.g. if you have `file.fbx,d/1.1234.gz`, you can unzip that and you'll have the content of `file.fbx` as of change 1234.  Each gzip file is a complete revision on its own; you don't need to glue them together or anything like that.

Note that without the database (the db.* files), you may not be able to put together the exact original structure of the depot; the back-end archive files don't exactly correspond to the depot layout since archive files may be "lazy copied" to multiple locations in the depot.

Comment: Don't have enough rep to +1 but opening the zip file, and extracting whatever was in there then adding the .fbx extension did the trick for me! Thanks a bunch for your help!